# Polling over a large number of IO connections in Java

Tags: java, asynchronous, future

Basically my problem is this : i have a server answering on a port to a (large) number of requests and each of those requests translates into 1 or more parallel calls to other services on other machines. Doing a thread per request would not be efficient in this case so i'm trying to come with a way to implement it in a async way. My solution so far consists of basically keeping all the future objects that represent the connections to the outside services in a array and continuously looping over it in a dedicated thread, adding the finished ones to a BlockingQueue for further processing. Is this efficient?

Is there a better way of doing this? The array is made of future objects basically because the handler used to call the outside services will do it's own share of async stuff beneath the hood so i can rely on the future returning interface to take care of that IO efficiently.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If for some limitation you cannot re-write the package into some event/callback driven interface, use CompletionService.

Comment: isn't that moving the problem from one place to another ? I mean i still end up looping over take/poll and pushing the complete future objects someplace else. Looping over a future ConcurrentLinkedQueue , asking isDone on each of them seems to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 0):

[Dataflow for Java](https://github.com/rfqu/df4j) framework is created for such tasks. It can be easily integrated with Java7 nio2 asynchronous network library, as demonstrated in [pipeline-nio](https://github.com/rfqu/pipeline/tree/master/pipeline-nio) project.